# What does "thermodynamic equilibrium" mean for an enzyme-substrate complex?

Tags: enzymes, enzyme-kinetics

From Fersht, Enzyme Structure and Mechanism p. 87:

> The Michaelis-Menten mechanism assumes that the enzyme-substrate
>   complex is in thermodynamic equilibrium with free enzyme and
>   substrate.

In my understanding what this means is that the (E-, S- and ES-concentration dependent) rates of association and dissociation have equated.
So we're kind of in this situation:
[image]

where "product" would be referring to [ES] and "reactant" to [E] and [S]. Does that make sense?

Comment: Product is still $P$; $ES$ is the transient Enzyme-Substrate complex. If you mean product in the sense of product of a reaction then yes but it is a confusing usage. So stick to calling $ES$ as a transient state

Comment: @tmottm Can you please accept answers, which answer your question satisfactory? This is a nice gesture towards the people who write the answers. You can find all your questions in your User menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thermodynamic equilibrium means that:

Rate of forward reaction = Rate of backward reaction

In this case:

$E + S\xrightleftharpoons[k2]{k1} ES\\ \ \\
 \ \\ \\ at\ equilibrium:\\ \  \ \\ \ k1.[E][S] \tiny{\ (forward\ rate)}\normalsize=  k2.[ES] \tiny\ (backward\ rate)
$

This was the initial assumption in the Michaelis-Menten model.

Later on this was improvised by assuming **pseudo-steady state** of ES complex. This means that $[ES]$ does not change over time, which is both as a result of its production by the reversible reaction:  $E + S \leftrightharpoons\ ES$ and consumption by the irreversible reaction $\ ES\ \xrightarrow{k3} E+P$

that is:

$k1[E][S]\tiny\ (production)\normalsize=(k2+k3)[ES]\tiny\ (consumption)$